# Methods of reducing time constant for an LR circuit

Tags: current, resistance, inductance, time-constant

Given a circuit/system with inductance and resistance, a certain time constant can be calculated for reaching maximum current.

1. Is the time constant calculated as 63% of the maximum current?
2. if L and R cannot be changed, are there other methods of reaching the maximum 100% current faster?

Comment: Is there a specific circuit you're working with here? Because an ideal source into an L and R, everything linear, and absolutely nothing other than that, has exactly two degrees of freedom, and if you've fixed those elements, you have none left, so it's not clear what you're asking.  (Would a "no" suffice?)

Comment: A henry divided by an ohm is a second. So there's not much you can do about that fact if you are stuck with the inductance and resistance you have in hand. If reaching a certain current in a certain time is important, a remaining thing that may be done is to change the applied voltage and then back it off to whatever the nominal value should be once the desired current is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write more, of course. But here's what I was thinking:

[image]

Note that the circuit on the right side of the schematic is a simple circuit that just applies the nominal voltage. The left side is the modified circuit.

The time constant here is \$5 \:\text{ms}\$. So it takes about 6 of those periods of time to reach the \$120\:\text{mA}\$ through the coil on the right. (Yes, it reaches about 63% in one time constant or \$5 \:\text{ms}\$.)

If you wanted to reach the full \$120\:\text{mA}\$, for example, in just one time constant (\$5 \:\text{ms}\$) then you'd need to apply a larger voltage. Here on the left, I applied \$19\:\text{V}\$ for \$5 \:\text{ms}\$ and then reduced it to the nominal \$12\:\text{V}\$. (The red line is the applied voltage.) You can see that this causes it (the green line) to reach the final level in less time.

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the input voltage above the normal maximum. The output voltage will still take one time constant to reach 63% of the input voltage - but the input voltage is higher, so (depending on how high you can make the input)  can zoom right past whatever voltage you actually need it to be. When the output voltage is the voltage you need it to be, bring the input voltage back down to normal.